# How to diagnose in Android (RadioGroup in ScrollView)

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I wanted to place a working RadioGroup inside a ScrollView.

This `main.xml` caused the app to blow up on load... "Sorry! The application... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Force close"

```
    <ScrollView>
        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types">
                    ...
```

And this worked

```
    <ScrollView>
        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            ....
```

My question, though, is **how to figure this out?** (aside from [trying out random code I find on the Internet](http://www.droidnova.com/layout-technique-static-elements-below-scrollview,123.html)). On the force close, the stack trace seems to just be a bunch of launcher stuff, and **never** mentions my `main.xml` (using Debug mode in Eclipse with an AVD). **Is there an error message somewhere that says that these attributes are missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to Debug**

You should see an error similar to this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

in the [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat) system debug output.

**Requirements**

Width and height are always required. In the [Layout Parameters section in the "Declaring Layout"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params) official Dev Guide, it says

> All view groups include a width and height (layout_width and layout_height), and **each view is required to define them**. Many LayoutParams also include optional margins and borders.

Also in the "[Layout Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html)" Dev Guide, it is stated that all subclasses of **View** require these two attributes

```
android:layout_height
```

> Dimension or keyword. **Required**. The height for the element, as a dimension value (or dimension resource) or a keyword ("fill_parent" or "wrap_content"). See the valid values below.

```
android:layout_width
```

> Dimension or keyword. **Required**. The width for the element, as a dimension value (or dimension resource) or a keyword ("fill_parent" or "wrap_content"). See the valid values below.

Comment: cool, this goes over how to access logcat in eclipse, and mentions that it's a bit buggy http://www.winksaville.com/blog/programming/debug-logging-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is to use Debug mode) When system throws an exception it appears in LogCat and you can find details of issue there. In your case you will get something like that: [image]